# How to add a space after currency symbol in CakePHP (3.0)?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

The question is actually pretty simple. I have the following code to display my currency on my page. `$this->Number->currency($HdViewBestellingen->INKBLPRIJS, 'EUR')` This prints out the curreny like:

> €0.12

But I want the currency to print out like:

> € 0.12

(notice the space between the € symbol and the number).

My question is, how do I achieve this using the CakePHP number formatter?

After reading http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/number.html#formatting-currency-values. 
I have been messing around with the options array which can be passed as well like `$this->Number->currency($HdViewBestellingen->INKBLPRIJS, 'EUR', ['pattern' => '#, ####.##'])` but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: actually I do have a space between the euro symbol and the currency in my pages... How is your locale set?

Comment: I think its set to en_US (assuming this is where it's set ini_set('intl.default_locale', 'en_US'); found in bootstrap.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the locale you are using. The locale also controls the position of the symbol.

If you use en_US then there are no spaces between the symbol and the number.

I suggest you to use any of the european locale. If you don't want to change it at application level in bootstrap.php you can set it just for one occurence like so

```
$this->Number->currency($HdViewBestellingen->INKBLPRIJS,'EUR', ['locale' => 'it_IT'])
```

I used italian locale because if you use german locale the euro symbol comes after the number

Comment: If you use the locale you recommended (it_IT) the euro sign comes after the price, this is also not what I want. However if I just found out if you use the locale nl_NL it does put the price as I want (so like € 0.12 with the space).